# Android Studio Webservice call "HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 401" Unauthorized

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, call, unauthorized

i try to connect my Android application to a Webservice.
I wrote a new class and defined some Variables:

I´ve got the Async Class to use the Network

```
class GetValueTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
        //wird im Background Thread ausgeführt
        return  params[0].getValue();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //wird im Mainthread ausgeführt
        MainActivity.this.setText(s);
    }
}
```

And I have a Class where i want to call the Webservice

```
public class ApiConnector
{
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/AddService:Add";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME ="Add";
    private static final String NAMESPACE ="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/AddService";
    private static final String URL ="http://192.168.0.154:9047/DynamicsNAV80/WS/CRONUS%20AG/Codeunit/AddService";
    private static final String USERNAME="B.Denger";
    private static final String PASSWORD ="TestPW123!";



    public String getValue() {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("no","10");

        PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Username
        unamePI.setName("username");
        // Set Value
        unamePI.setValue(USERNAME);
        // Set dataType
        unamePI.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(unamePI);
        //Set Password
        passPI.setName("password");
        //Set dataType
        passPI.setValue(PASSWORD);
        //Set dataType
        passPI.setType(String.class);
        //Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(passPI);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE aht= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            return resultString.toString();
        }catch(Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Fail at Call";
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the using-permission in the Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in my MainActivity do i execute the AsynkTask with a Button

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetValueTask getValueTask = new GetValueTask();
            getValueTask.execute(new ApiConnector());
        }
    });
```

after execution i get following Logcat entry:

```
W/System.err﹕ org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 401
```

i googled a whole Day for it, but i did not solved the problem yet.
is there anybody who could help me, or could give me a hint where i have to search?

Comment: Have you succeeded using those credentials from somewhere else, like a browser or fiddler / wireshark / etc?

Comment: yes, i can call the WS with the Internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

[Android Consuming Dynamics NAV SOAP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214364/android-consuming-dynamics-nav-soap-web-service)

but it didnt Work with the jcif 1.3.17 jar
at https://jcifs.samba.org/src/ can you download the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed same problem by adding this code:

```
List<HeaderProperty> llstHeadersProperty = new ArrayList<>();
llstHeadersProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes())));
loHttpTransport.call(sSOAP_ACTION, loEnvelope, llstHeadersProperty);
```

Complete task:

```
private class fnAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //for linear parameter
            SoapObject loRequest = new SoapObject(sNAMESPACE, sMETHOD_NAME);
            // adding method property here serially
//            loRequest.addProperty("CountryName", "france");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope loEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            loEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
            loEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(loRequest);
            loEnvelope.dotNet = true;


            HttpTransportSE loHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(_sURL);
            loHttpTransport.debug = true;
            try
            {
                List<HeaderProperty> llstHeadersProperty = new ArrayList<>();
                llstHeadersProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes())));
                loHttpTransport.call(sSOAP_ACTION, loEnvelope, llstHeadersProperty);
            }
            catch (HttpResponseException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("HTTPLOG", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("IOLOG", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("XMLLOG", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //send request

            Object result = null;
            try {
                result = (Object )loEnvelope.getResponse();
                //See output in the console
                Log.i("RESPONSE",String.valueOf(result));
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("SOAPLOG", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Full example
http://www.nascenia.com/consuming-soap-web-services-from-android/